# How to run android applications on a windows 8.x /10?

Tags: android, windows

How can I run android applications on a windows 8.x /10 with full screen functionality so the screen real estate on the android app(when running on windows) is maximized to full screen ?  I cannot use emulators as I've run into the real estate problem.

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Did You try  running Android Emulators ??

Comment: Search something called bluestack. I guess it would help !!

Comment: you **obviously** can't run non-windows app on windows without emulating the system, for which the app is made.